# Magento 2 master slave connection for DB

Tags: magento2, database, database-connection, master-slave

I am planning to enable Master and slave connection on my Magento site.
Magento team suggest me to check my 3rd party and custom modules support this master/slave config or not.

I am not sure how can I check it. 
suggestions are much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to check all third party modules that they do not do following things

Source Ref : [Split database performance solution (Magento Commerce only)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master.html)

> Because of the way the split database performance solution is designed, your custom code and installed components cannot do any of the following:

- Write directly to the database (instead, you must use the Magento Commerce database 
  interface)
- Use JOINs that affect the sales or quote databases
- Use foreign keys to tables in the checkout, sales, or main databases